# How to avoid slow startup / OSX won't save spotlight index?

Tags: macos, mac, performance, osx-lion, spotlight

Lately I've been having issues with osx taking a CRAZY long time to start up. Every time it does start, I have this hunch that, considering how hard spotlight is working after startup, that it might have something to do with it. Checking out activity monitor, everything is more or less normal before and after startup.

Is this normal? I can't remember this happening when I first got this macbook. Speaking of which, it's 10.7, 2.7 ghz lion.

Comment: You'll know when it reindexes, e.g. after a crash, because it will show up in the Spotlight menu when you click the icon.

Comment: Daniel, that's exactly what's happening. But it was just a normal restart, without any crashes involved. It takes quite a long time, as well, to finish.

Comment: one of index files might be a little corrupted, so system decides to reindex. I'd recommend to turn indexing off, since it takes alot of resouces